# Protobuf RuntimeTypeModel for Java

Tags: protobuf-net

i have quite complicated inheritance structure in .net that includes generic classes. 
example

```
abstract class A{}
abstract class B<T> : A {}
sealed class C : B<CResponse>{}
sealed Class D : B<DResponse>{}
```

and so on. 
Then there is Request class that contains multiple A. and Request is then serialized.
im using RuntimeTypeModel in protobuf-net v2 to serialize the objects created, which is an ideal solution. when i deserialize in .net, the TypeModel helps me get the schema and resolves  types on its own. 
how do i get it deserialized in java. is there a RuntimeTypeModel available there? also even if i create proto files for above hierarchy(which will be manually), how would i know which objects builder to call. 
if its not possible to do this way , can you suggest a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Neither generics nor inheritance is directly supported by protobuf itself; protobuf-net mimics inheritance via encapsulation, of the form (in .proto terms):

```
message A {
    optional B_CResponse B_CResponse = ?;
    optional B_DResponse B_DResponse = ?;
}
message B_CResponse {
    optional C C = ?;
}
message B_DResponse {
    optional D D = ?;
}
message C {
}
message D {
}
```

You can obviously add any members as needed, and need to replace the ? with the actual field-numbers. You should be able to use "protoc" to generate a compatible model from that.

The standard Java implementation has nothing like RuntimeTypeModel AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks a ton Marc. I have this working successfully. Quick question about datetime fields. i dont have them as utc and it will be quite hard for me to add new fields in string or long for datetime. is there a way to handle this?